# Run MVC4 webapplication on local IIS webserver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-tenant

**UPDATED** - pointed to the wrong directory at first. Thanks for the tip **Wiktor**. Still not succeeded in running the MVC4 application via

I am trying (for a while now.. :)) to set up a simulated multi tenant webapp on my development PC. I learned that this is not possible with visual studio's internal webserver, so I am trying to set up IIS.

I added the `fake` tenants in my hosts.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 tenant1.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 tenant2.mydomain.com
```

In IIS I made a new website `test`(port 8081), and just pointed it to `C:\Azure\Websites\`. In that directory I added a `Hello World` html file to see if this bit works.

- I navigated to localhost:8081 => Hello world
- I navigated to tenant1.mydomain.com:8081 => Hello world.

Cool, first proof of life.

---

Next step: getting this working with a MVC4 webapp created in VS2012.

I started a new MVC4 webapp and stored it in:
`C:\Azure\Websites\MvcApplication1`

I just use the default generated website for the test, so I pressed `F5` and verified the site is opened in firefox. So the goal is to get this working from IIS.

- Created a new website `test2` (port 8082)
- Set test2 app pool to .net4.0
- Point the physical directory to `C:\Azure\Websites\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\`
- Navigate to localhost:8082

**HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list**

Uninstalled ASP.NET and reinstalled it again. Same results.

when I change web.config from

```
preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
```

to

```
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
```

Then I get this error:

**HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.**

Can I stress the fact that I am a n00b regarding IIS configuration... :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not point to mvcapplication\bin but rather to mvcapplication.

Comment: Ah ok. Gave me a new error which I will look in to (HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error)

Comment: Is your app pool set to asp 4.0?

Comment: Yes apppool is running .net4.0

Comment: from one error to another. updated last bit of my question. pretty much lost here.... :)

Comment: yo! got it. had to add isapi for 4.0 in isapi cgi restiction. not really a clue what i did, but it works :)

Comment: You learn once and then you do it woken up in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISAPI and CGI Restictions in IIS:

- Add isapi dll for .net 4 32bit
- Add isapi dll for .net 4 64bit

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

And it works. Finally!

Thanks Wiktor

Comment: Would it be better to install these by selecting them in the Turn Windows Features on or off section of Programs and Features in the Control Panel?  Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features

Answer (score 0):

First configure IIS according [this site](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/install-sitefinity/configuring-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects):

IIS 7.5 handler "`extensionlessurlhandler-integrated-4.0`" has a bad module "`managedpipelinehandler`" in its module list

For the above issue, you must go to Control Panel >> Installed Programs and Features >> Repair your .NET Framework by double clicking on it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @PeterFoti In my opinion this isn't a link-only answer. It may be VLQ, but is definitely not link-only.

Answer (score 0):

first configure IIS as 
Manual configuration 
Open your Control Panel and click Programs and Features » Turn Windows features on or off.
Turn on Internet Information Services.

Under Internet Information Services, turn on the following features:
Web Management Tools » IIS 6 Management Compatibility » IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility.

Web Management Tools » IIS Management Console, IIS Management Scripts and Tools, and Management Service.

Under World Wide Web Services, turn on the following:
All features under Application Development features, except Server-Side Includes.
Common HTTP Features » Default Document, Directory Browsing, HTTP errors, Http Redirection, Static Content.
Security » Basic Authentication, Request Filtering, Windows Authentication.

Under Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 » Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation.

After you have created your website, open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manger.
Expand your server node.
Expand Sites node and click your website.

In section IIS on the right, double-click Authentication.
Perform one of the following:

If you are using Forms authentication, make sure Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication are enabled and all other authentications are disabled.

If you are using Claims-based authentication, make sure only Anonymous Authentication is enabled and all other authentications are disabled.

Click your website again and in IIS section, double-click Handler Mappings.
Make sure you have enabled handler mappings for *.svc and *.xamlx with executable path set to one of the following:

For 64-bit OS: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
For 32-bit OS: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
Close the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manger.